# How to create a globally visible variable?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, global-variables

How can I declare a variable and use it in all files? For example i have:

```
MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("blablabla");
```

I want to use cn in all files without declaring it.

Comment: You can use static field/property in some class. But that's not very good idea to share connection across all files

Comment: There are no global variables in C#. You can work around it with composition or inheritance, but that's ugly. Rethink your design instead.

Comment: You can just make everything in your program be a static member of one big do-it-all class

Comment: @JeroenVannevel public static properties can be seen as global variables.

Comment: @Crono: they are what they are: public static properties. You have to access the containing class to get the variable. They might be globally visible variables, but I interpreted the question as the variable being directly a part of the class.

Answer (score 12):

The straight answer to your question would be to make it public and static:

```
public static class Session
{
    static MySqlConnection _connection;

    public static MySqlConnection Connection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_connection == null)
            {
                // instantiate _connection here
            }

            return _connection;
        }
    }
}
```

You could then access it from anywhere using `Session.Connection`.

However, IMHO **this is a bad design decision**. Having a unique live instance of a connection throughout your application's lifecycle will not benefit you in any way. In fact it will actually make your life a nightmare for many different reasons, like unpredictable connection dropping, untimely opening/closing and multithreading hell.

You should instead have some sort of connection factory that will create a properly initalized connection object and return it back. *THAT* factory method could then be accessible globally.

```
public static ConnectionFactory
{
    public static MySqlConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        // create and return your MySqlConnection object
    }
}
```

And then, from anywhere in your code:

```
using (var cn = ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection())
{
    // do data-related stuff
}
```

The `using` statement here will make sure your connection instance will be properly disposed of once you are done with it, freeing your app from useless overhead and relieving the server from keeping an open channel to the client.

As [ADO.NET best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx#adonetbest_topic5) states:

> High performance applications keep connections to the data source in
>   use for a minimal amount of time, (...)

Bear that in mind any time you are building a data-driven application.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can declare the connection string inside some `App.config` or `Web.config`.

Then read the connectionString from there everytime you need it.

SOmething like in this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection 
    connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Here some info about this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use the **[Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)**.

```
    class MySqlConnection
    {
        private static MySqlConnection _Instance;
        public static MySqlConnection Instance()
        {
            return _Instance == null ? _Instance = new MySqlConnection () : _Instance;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you use WPF application you can declare your variable in a class that is an App partial class.

1. create a class  nameyouwant.cs

in code behind:

```
public partial class App
{
    #region - your global variable - 
    public MySqlConnection Cn
    {
        get;
        set;
    } ="blablablá"
    #endregion
 }
```

in any part of your project you can use it in this way:

in xaml:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockExampler" Text="{Binding Cn, Source={x:Static Application.Current}"/>
```

in code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
.....
string texting = (Application.Current as App).Cn
....
```

that's it.